# How to call a function within a procedure to update all records of a table on PLSQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm practicing PLSQL and I'm coding a package with 2 functions to update commission and the other one to update salary but now I want to create a procedure within the same package to update commission and salary for all employees using the functions on the package. Is it possible?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_upd_pkg IS

  -- Function to update commission_pct --
  FUNCTION comm_upd(
    p_empid employees.commission_pct%TYPE)
    RETURN NUMBER
  IS
    v_new_comm   employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    UPDATE employees
    SET    commission_pct = commission_pct * 1.1
    WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;

    SELECT commission_pct
    INTO   v_new_comm
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;
    RETURN v_new_comm;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN
      NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20992, 'NO EXISTE EMPLEADO');
  END comm_upd;

  -- Function to update salary --
  FUNCTION sal_upd(
    p_empid employees.salary%TYPE)
  RETURN employees.salary%TYPE
  IS
    v_newsal employees.salary%TYPE;
  BEGIN
    UPDATE employees
    SET    salary = salary + 350
    WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;

    -- Consulta select para la salida del a funcion --
    SELECT salary
    INTO   v_newsal
    FROM   employees
    WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;
    RETURN v_newsal;
  END sal_upd;

  -- Procedure to update all records of employees table --
  PROCEDURE comm_sal_upd(
    p_new_comm employees.commission_pct%TYPE,
    p_new_sal  employees.salary%TYPE);

END emp_upd_pkg;
```

I've tried creating a cursor and fetching into functions but I didn't succeed.

```
PROCEDURE comm_sal_upd(
    p_new_comm employees.commission_pct%TYPE,
    p_new_sal  employees.salary%TYPE)
    IS
 CURSOR emp_cur IS
  SELECT commission_pct, salary
  FROM   employees;
BEGIN
  OPEN emp_cur;
  FETCH emp_cur
  INTO  emp_upd_pkg.comm_upd(p_comm), emp_upd_pkg.sal_upd(p_sal);
  CLOSE emp_cur;
END comm_sal_upd;
```

Comment: Your functions would make more sense as procedures. Also you pass in employee_ids, so they should be `employees.employee_id%TYPE`.

Comment: What do you want `comm_dal_upd` to do exactly? Should it apply the specified commission and salary adjustments to all employees? If so, your commission and salary procedures/functions should accept `p_new_comm` and `p_new_sal` as parameters and use those instead of the hardcoded values.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually I think you are right, so Is possible code a procedure and later use RETURNING attribute to use as parameter to comm_sal_upd procedure?- com,_sal_upd is a procedure to update salary and commision of all employees using comm_upd and sal_upd funcitions.

Comment: Yes but what are the `p_new_comm` and  `p_new_sal` parameters for?

Comment: Well I've created these parameters to assign new salary and new commission of all employees but now I understood your point. It's not necessary add parameters to procedure because salary and commission conditions are in the other functions!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, few tricks to improve your functions.

You don't need to make two queries when you can make one. Instead of

```
  v_new_comm   employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
BEGIN
  UPDATE employees
  SET    commission_pct = commission_pct * 1.1
  WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;

  SELECT commission_pct
  INTO   v_new_comm
  FROM   employees
  WHERE  employee_id = p_empid;
  RETURN v_new_comm;
```

use `returning` clause:

```
  v_new_comm   employees.commission_pct%TYPE;
BEGIN
  UPDATE employees
  SET    commission_pct = commission_pct * 1.1
  WHERE  employee_id = p_empid
  returning commission_pct
  into   v_new_comm;

  RETURN v_new_comm;
```

Also, this exception block doesn't look like very helpful:

```
EXCEPTION
  WHEN
    NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20992, 'NO EXISTE EMPLEADO');
```

You just change the language of the error message.

As for the procedure to update all records, there are several issues:

- You should avoid update many records one by one, it significantly reduces the performance. If possible, update them all together:

  ```
  UPDATE employees
  SET    commission_pct = commission_pct * 1.1,
         salary = salary + 350;
  ```
- Cursors don't work this way. You shold use them to select data.
- To process all rows in cursors, use loops:

  ```
  PROCEDURE comm_sal_upd(
      p_new_comm employees.commission_pct%TYPE,
      p_new_sal  employees.salary%TYPE)
      IS
   CURSOR emp_cur IS
    SELECT commission_pct, salary
    FROM   employees;
    v_comission number;
    v_salary    number;
  BEGIN
    OPEN emp_cur;
    loop
      FETCH emp_cur INTO v_comission, v_salary;
      EXIT WHEN emp_cur%NOTFOUND;
      <do something>
    end loop;
    CLOSE emp_cur;
  END comm_sal_upd;
  ```

With one `FETCH` you process only one record.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are right, now I have an idea for code this procedure. but the point is I need make the procedure with the functions. I will try now.

Answer (score 1):

You are using function so its returing a value. you must capture the value in your procedure as below:

```
PROCEDURE comm_sal_upd(
    p_new_comm employees.commission_pct%TYPE,
    p_new_sal  employees.salary%TYPE)
    IS
 CURSOR emp_cur IS
  SELECT commission_pct, salary
  FROM   employees;

  var number;
  var2 employees.salary%TYPE;

BEGIN

  for rec in   emp_cur
   loop

   var:= emp_upd_pkg.comm_upd(p_comm);
   var2:=emp_upd_pkg.sal_upd(p_sal);

   dbms_output.put_line('updated commission--'|| var || ' Updated Sal -- '|| var2);

   end loop;

 commit;
END comm_sal_upd;
```

Comment: Yes, You are right but I don¿t have any idea how to make it!! I will try with your code an later will paste my new code. Thanks

Comment: I have already given the idea in my solution. Read it line by line.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is the kind of thing you are trying to do. (Untested, probably has bugs.) Note this is the least efficient way to do anything in PL/SQL, so it's just to demonstrate how you might structure procedures that call each other.

(btw I don't know if there is some textbook out there that tells people to code in uppercase, but there is really no need to.)

```
create or replace package body emp_upd_pkg
as
    -- Update commission_pct for one employee:
    procedure comm_upd
        ( p_empid     employees.employee_id%type
        , p_new_comm  employees.commission_pct%type )
    is
    begin
        update employees set commission_pct = commission_pct * p_new_comm
        where  employee_id = p_empid;

        if sql%rowcount = 0 then
            raise_application_error(-20992, 'Commission update failed: employee id ' || p_empid || ' not found.', false); 
        end if;
    end comm_upd;


    -- Update salary for one employee:
    procedure sal_upd
        ( p_empid    employees.employee_id%type
        , p_new_sal  employees.salary%type )
    is
    begin
        update employees set salary = salary + p_new_sal
        where  employee_id = p_empid;

        if sql%rowcount = 0 then
            raise_application_error(-20993, 'Salary update failed: employee id ' || p_empid || ' not found.', false); 
        end if;
    end sal_upd;


    -- Update all employees:
    procedure comm_sal_upd
        ( p_new_comm  employees.commission_pct%type
        , p_new_sal   employees.salary%type )
    is
    begin
        for r in (
            select employee_id from employees
        )
        loop
            comm_upd(r.employee_id, p_new_comm);
            sal_upd(r.employee_id, p_new_sal);
        end loop;
    end comm_sal_upd;

end emp_upd_pkg;
```